# Ubuntu 20.04 x11vnc blank (not black) screen after session login

Tags: remote-access, ubuntu-20.04, vnc

I have a remote headless server without a monitor attached with SSH access.

From what I found out the hard way, the default install does not support VNC (using vino) without a monitor attached.

Tried several things to get this working this without success.

I followed this guide on setting up x11vnc and lightdm: https://www.crazy-logic.co.uk/projects/computing/how-to-install-x11vnc-vnc-server-as-a-service-on-ubuntu-20-04-for-remote-access-or-screen-sharing

I then also tried to install xubuntu-desktop, which did not help.

The issue is:

- VNC asks for password and connects. All good.
- I see the session login window (with the panel at the top), everything looks ok. All good.
  [screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D550h.png)
- After login I only see a blank screen. Nothing responds. Right click on the desktop does not open a context menu. Not good.
  [screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGLIl.png)

Expected would be to see the desktop, panels, menus...etc.

How would one solve this? And what exactly is happening here. The session logs show everything is ok, no errors. But the computer is unresponsive on VNC, only the background is visible.

Note: I do not have physical access to this server. A solution via SSH would be best.

Comment: Try this answer. Worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70820064/ubuntu-not-responding-after-login-20-04/70820065#70820065

Comment: @user7474631 this answer does not exist. What was it that worked for you?